# How bind a custom ContentType with activity CreateTaskWithContentType ?

Tags: list, workflow, content-type, tasks, properties

When I create a task with activity "CreateTaskWithContentType", I can't bind a custom ContentType with the list "Tasks".

For the moment I try to bind my CT  with the correct path in properties windows and by this way in file "Workflow1.cs":

task1.ContentTypeId1 = "0x01080100c3f79a5973a84faaab4ac83e939ec5ef";

ContentTypeId1 is an DependencyProperty of task1.

But it doesn't work. The CT is on my solution because when I check it in "Site Settings/Site Content Type", I find it.

Do you have any idea how I can do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you associated the content type with the task list for the workflow?

See [A few things you should know about CreateTaskWithContentType in SharePoint Workflow](http://thorprojects.com/blog/archive/2007/01/24/a-few-things-you-should-know-about-createtaskwithcontenttype-in-sharepoint-workflow.aspx)